# Mapping two lists in Python to a dictionary results in fewer items?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists, containing 50 items:

`print(len(per_column[0]))` returns 50 items, and `print(len(per_column[1]))` also returns 50 items.

I would like to make this into a dictionary. So I do:

`HashDict = dict(zip(per_column[0], per_column[1]))`

but this results in a dictionary containing 47 items only, not 50 (as verified by `print(len(HashDict))` ). Taking one step back, if I only zip the lists (without creating the dictionary), I in fact do get 50 items still:

`zipList = zip(per_column[0], per_column[1])`

There seems to be something going awry when I try to convert the zipped list into a dictionary. Am I overlooking something??

Comment: So what does `print(len(set(per_column[0])))` tell you?

Comment: `print(len(set(per_column[0])))` returns 47 items. So this means that there are duplicate items in per_column[0]? @MartijnPieters

Comment: Exactly; you have 47 unique values. The other 3 are repeats.

Comment: Great, thank you! I appreciate your help, and I have been able to confirm there are duplicate values. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first list only has 47 *unique* items; the older items are being replaced by the newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you lose items, it will be because of duplicate keys in `per_column[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is duplicate values in your first list. Since `dict` cannot contain duplicate keys, its length will be shorter. You can find the duplicate values in your list using:

```
from collections import Counter

fields = Counter(per_column[0])
print fields.most_common()
```

Comment: This is helpful in showing which items are duplicates, thanks for this!